# Java: Help outputting to a file?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, java-io

Working on a Java project for a class. Professor wants us to output to a file, which I've never done before.
Instructions: 
    Create program1.states.in.out and include it in your project folder when you submit your project.
    This file is NOT to appear like the displayed output in Step 3.  It is to consist of only the 
    unformatted data lines (not spaced out; no headers….).  The output file, then, will consist of fifty 
    data lines only.   You will need this created copy for your input again ahead in Step 6.  So 
    ensure it is formatted correctly.  It will look like:

```
Texas          Austin         TX19759614Southwest      5
New_Mexico     Santa_Fe       NM 1736931Southwest      5
Arizona        Phoenix        AZ 4668631Southwest      5
```

This looks to be the same structure from his input file. But I've already trimmed/parsed that to fill the State array. How would I get it back into this format, then output it to a file?

Code used to trim/parse from the input file (in main):

```
inputString = br1.readLine();
        while (inputString != null) {
            stateName = inputString.substring(0, 15).trim();
            stateCapital = inputString.substring(15, 30).trim();
            stateAbbrev = inputString.substring(30, 32).trim();
            statePop = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(32, 40).trim());
            stateRegion = inputString.substring(40, 55).trim();
            stateRegionNum = Integer.parseInt(inputString.substring(55));
            Sdriver.insert(stateName, stateCapital, stateAbbrev, statePop, stateRegion, stateRegionNum);
            inputString = br1.readLine();    // read next input line.
        }
        br1.close();     //Close input file being read
```

And this is the State.class.

```
public class State {
   private String stateName;    
   private String stateCapital;
   private String stateAbbrev;
   private int statePop;
   private String stateRegion;
   private int stateRegionNum;
   public static final String HEADER_STRING = "\n%-15s  %-15s  %-4s  %-10s  %-15s  %-8s\n\n";
   private static final String DISPLAY_STRING = "%-15s  %-15s  %-4s  %,10d  %-15s  %1d";

    public State(String name, String capital, String abbrev, int pop, String region, int regionNum) {
      stateName = name;
      stateCapital = capital;
      stateAbbrev = abbrev;
      statePop = pop;
      stateRegion = region;
      stateRegionNum = regionNum;
      }//End State

   public void displayState(int nElems, State myState[]) {
      System.out.print(String.format(State.HEADER_STRING, "State", "Capital", "Abbr", "Population", "Region", "Region #"));

        for(int x = 0; x < nElems - 1; x++) {
            System.out.println(myState[x].toString());
       } 
   }//End displayState
```

Edit: My attempted Code to output.

```
String file = "src/program1.states.in.out.txt";
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/program1.states.in.out.txt")); {
            for(int x = 0; x < Sdriver.getnElems(); x++) {
                writer.write(Sdriver.getState(x).toString());
            }
        }
```

Created a file, but the file was empty.

Comment: Your input reading appears too complex to me. Myself, I'd just split each line with something like `"\s+"`. For output, you'd use the displayState method for creating a String that you write to file. You should try doing this yourself first before asking for our help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you have not yet posted your attempt to solve this first, and this is necessary if we're to see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks. What if you wrapped your BufferedWriter in a PrintWriter object, say called printWriter, and simply change the inner part of the for loop to `printWriter.println(Sdriver.getState(x).displayState());`?

Comment: I need to pass it an int and State[]. But it wont accept nElems or myState, because those variables are located in another class, StateCollection.

Comment: Those are details that you will have to work out for yourself. You will have to pass references from one class to another, but I'm sure that you'll figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You look to be starting in not too bad a spot with this:

```
String file = "src/program1.states.in.out.txt";
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("src/program1.states.in.out.txt")); {
    for(int x = 0; x < Sdriver.getnElems(); x++) {
        writer.write(Sdriver.getState(x).toString());
    }
}
```

But consider instead using a PrintWriter object and the `displayState()` method. Something akin to:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = null;
try {
    String filePath = "src/program1.states.in.out.txt";
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
    for(int x = 0; x < Sdriver.getnElems(); x++) {
        printWriter.println(Sdriver.getState(x).displayState());
    }
} catch (IOException ioE) {
    ioE.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (printWriter != null) {
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```